# Define queue concurrency per queue

Tags: laravel-vapor

For Larvel Vapor we can define multiple queues

Exmaple form official docs:

```
id: 2
name: vapor-laravel-app
environments:
    production:
        queues:
            - emails
            - invoices
```

Also can define queue concurrency

Example form official docs:

```
id: 2
name: vapor-laravel-app
environments:
    production:
        queue-concurrency: 50
        build:
            - 'composer install --no-dev'
```

Can we define concurrency per each queue separately?

Something I'm expecting:

```
id: 2
name: vapor-laravel-app
environments:
    production:
        queues:
            emails
                queue-concurrency: 50
            invoices
                queue-concurrency: 20
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reply Received From Official Laravel Vapor Developers**

It is not possible at the moment

2022-05-10